IB().connect raises TimeoutError in ib_insync library
I have been trying to place orders using the ib_insync library in through IBKR trading workstation. In one of the accounts there is an error in IB.connect and it raises TimeoutError.
here is the line:
ib = IB().connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, clientId=123)

Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "...Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\_init.py", line 1921, in __call__
        return self.func(*args)
      File "nq_ibkr_algo.py", line 193, in initiate_functionalities
        self.ib, self.contract = self.ib_connection()
      File "nq_ibkr_algo.py", line 452, in ib_connection
        ib = IB().connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, clientId=123)
  
     File "venv\lib\site-packages\ib_insync\ib.py", line 279, in connect
        return self._run(self.connectAsync(
      File "venv\lib\site-packages\ib_insync\ib.py", line 318, in _run
        return util.run(*awaitables, timeout=self.RequestTimeout)
      File "venv\lib\site-packages\ib_insync\util.py", line 341, in run
        result = loop.run_until_complete(task)
      File "Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
        return future.result()
      File "venv\lib\site-packages\ib_insync\ib.py", line 1782, in connectAsync
        await asyncio.wait_for(self.reqExecutionsAsync(), timeout)
      File "Python\Python310\lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 458, in wait_for
        raise exceptions.TimeoutError() from exc
    asyncio.exceptions.TimeoutError

I was expecting it to run smoothly like other accounts of IBKR but having issue with some specific trading accounts.
This error likely seems to be library related. It would be very helpful if someone could help me out with this.
Thank you

you can try a few things, maybe they will help:
update your libraries and dependencies. Maybe you were using older Versions.
pip install --upgrade ib-insync
pip install --upgrade ib-insync asyncio

Verify that the TWS/Gateway is running. Check API settings and ensure that ActiveX and Sockets Clients is enabled.
Maybe adjusting the timeout to 60 secs. will help:
ib = IB().connect('127.0.0.1', 7496, clientId=123, timeout=60)

If that didn't work either, then try using a different ClientID or check your Firewall-rules, maybe that solves it.
./Shad0w
